# Objective-c best data structure sortable of string and bool

Tags: objective-c, string, sorting, boolean, nsdictionary

I need to store a **list of strings** for my items in a TableView and **for each** string I need to store a **Bool value**.. I would use an **NSDictionary** but how can I **sort** the list of strings **alphabetically** (using a selector) and sort at the same time the bool values?

I know that exists methods like sortUsingSelector or UsingComparator, but in the NSDictionary I can only sort **keys by values** so I need the reverse..

Can anyone help me, maybe using another **Data Structure**?

Comment: If you sort the keys then the values are inherently sorted because you use the keys to access the values.

Comment: Why not make an array of dictionaries? Every dictionary contains a string and a bool. You can then sort the array using the string ;)

Comment: I found the solution with some trick and a bit by walking around.. thanks a lot for answers, You've helped me to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following data structure:

Use an NSArray of NSDictionaries like so (make it a property):

```
self.array = @[@{@"String": @"Zusuuuuu", @"bool": @0}, // I am really not creative ;-) Just wanted an unsorted example
               @{@"String": @"YourContent", @"bool": @0},
               @{@"String": @"YourOtherContent", @"bool": @1}];
```

You can then sort it like this:

```
self.array = [self.array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *aDictionary, NSDictionary *anotherDictionary) {
    return [aDictionary[@"String"] compare:anotherDictionary[@"String"]];
}];
```

If you want to populate your UITableView just do the following:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.array.count; //If you want them all in one section, easiest case
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ...
    // Do all the initialization of your cell
    // ...

    cell.yourLabel.text = self.array[indexPath.row][@"String"];
    cell.yourSwitch.on = ((NSNumber *)self.array[indexPath.row][@"bool"]).boolValue;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: how do you insert a new dictionary object, as you did, in a NSMutableArray?

I mean the equivalent of addObject: for a normal array

Comment: You cannot. A "normal" array is immutable (you cannot change it once it is initialized). That is when do your `alloc init` or `@[]` you cannot change its content anymore but since we work with pointers we can easily create a new array and let our pointer point to that newly created array.

Comment: I can't fill it all at once .. I need to fill one by one in an iteration. So if I use an NSMutableArray I can't follow your method?

Comment: @Shafa95 Your question doesn't make sense. You state that you already use `NSMutableArray`. You claim that you know how `addObject:` works on it. What's the problem?

Comment: I would do it like this:

`//PROVA ARRAY
 NSMutableDictionary *dizionario = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [dizionario setObject:@"record[i][tipologia]" forKey:@"Item"];
 [dizionario setObject:0 forKey:@"Bool"];
 [listaNonOrdinata addObject:dizionario];`

It's right?

Comment: I've never loaded an array as it has done HAS, so I was a bit puzzled .. But now I think I understand how to do it. Thanks